# Shared Preferences Not Saving

Tags: android

Shared Preferences in my settings dialog are not saving.  When I click save, and then re-open the dialog, the preferences are reset to the original values.  I feel like I am missing something.  Any help would be appreciated!

Notes:

1. This dialog appears in my main fragment.  Not sure if that makes a difference.
2. I have already tried edit.clear() before edit.commit() and it did not work.

Thank you!!

```
private void settingsButton() {

    if(soundsOn == true) {
        mplayerButtonClick.start();
    }
    //set up dialog
    final Dialog setupDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    setupDialog.setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    setupDialog.setTitle("Choose Settings");
    setupDialog.setCancelable(true);

    TextView topSettings = (TextView)setupDialog.findViewById(R.id.chosensettings);
    topSettings.setTypeface(tf);

    soundsToggle = (Switch)setupDialog.findViewById(R.id.soundstoggle);
    soundsToggle.setTypeface(tf);
    if(soundsOn == true){
        soundsToggle.setChecked(true);
    }else if(soundsOn == false){
        soundsToggle.setChecked(false);
    }
    soundsToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                s = true;
            } else {
                s = false;
            }

        }
    });

    cuesToggle = (Switch)setupDialog.findViewById(R.id.cuestoggle);
    cuesToggle.setTypeface(tf);
    final boolean cuesToggleOn = preferences.getBoolean("cues", true);
    if (cuesToggleOn == true){
        cuesToggle.setChecked(true);
    }else if(cuesToggleOn == false){
        cuesToggle.setChecked(false);
    }else{
        cuesToggle.setChecked(true);
    }
    cuesToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(cuesToggle.isChecked()){
                c = true;
            }else{
                c = false;
            }
        }
    });


    listOnlyToggle = (Switch)setupDialog.findViewById(R.id.listonly);
    listOnlyToggle.setTypeface(tf);
    listOnlyOn = preferences.getBoolean("listonly", false);
    if(listOnlyOn == true){
        listOnlyToggle.setChecked(true);
    }else if(listOnlyOn == false){
        listOnlyToggle.setChecked(false);
    }
    listOnlyToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                l = true;
            } else {
                l = false;
            }

        }
    });


    Button saveSetting = (Button)setupDialog.findViewById(R.id.save);
    saveSetting.setTypeface(tf);
    saveSetting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(soundsOn == true) {
                mplayerButtonClick.start();
            }

            if (s = true){
                editor.putBoolean("sounds", true);
                soundsOn = true;
            }else if (s = false) {
                editor.putBoolean("sounds", false);
                soundsOn = false;
            }

            if (c = true){
                editor.putBoolean("cues", true);
            }else if (c = false){
                editor.putBoolean("cues", false);
            }

             if (l = true){
                 editor.putBoolean("listonly", true);
             }else if (l = false){
                 editor.putBoolean("listonly", false);
              }

            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            setupDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    setupDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Try to create editor in `onClick` method

Comment: Use this condition `if (l) editor.putBoolean("listonly", true);else editor.putBoolean("listonly", true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition `s = true` is always 'true' .

**Description：**
This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations.

If you judge whether a value is a Boolean value, you need to use condition `if(s)`.

And if you use `if(s == true)` .

**Description：**
Reports pointless or pointlessly complicated boolean expressions. Such expressions include anding with true, oring with false, equality comparison with a boolean literal, or negation of a boolean literal. Such expressions may be the result of automated refactorings not completely followed through to completion, and in any case are unlikely to be what the developer intended to do.

**Better way  you use in your code is `if(s)` .**

Comment: Thank you so much!  I figured it was something simple I was missing.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Good luck to you.Enjoy coding.@SillyFidget

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change "if (s = true)" to "if (s)", where you should use condition checking instead of assignment.